# How to execute multiple stage operations in a single frame with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to execute multiple stage operations in one frame :

```
stage.sizeToScene()
stage.centerOnScreen()
```

Currently I can see that the stage is first resized, then centered. I would like both operations to be done *atomically* on the same *re-paint*.

Here is a working example :

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private HBox first = new HBox();
    private HBox second = new HBox();

    private Button change1 = new Button("Go to 2nd");
    private Button change2 = new Button("Go to 1st");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        first.setSpacing(10);
        first.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        first.getChildren().addAll(
            change1, new Label("Hello"), new Label("World")
        );
        second.setSpacing(10);
        second.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        second.getChildren().addAll(
            change2, new Label("BYE MY FRIENDS, THIS IS MUCH LONGER!")
        );
        change1.setOnAction(event -> {
            primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(second);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        });
        change2.setOnAction(event -> {
            primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(first);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(first));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

To reproduce, launch the application, move the window top-left and make it bigger. Then click on the button. You will see that the window is first resized, then moved at the center.

On this example case it's really really fast, because the application is really light. But with a real-world application it's much more noticable.

Comment: In which context do you execute these two commands? Can you provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @hotzst Done, thanks.

Comment: I don't visually see any indication that one action happens before the other, on OS X. Changing the order of operations which should make it more obvious by moving a big window into the middle of your screen also doesn't make the operations appear distinct.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. Also, the speed of the computer could make it visible or not.